# show heads-up notification kotlin android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

this is my code it only shows a simple notification how can i make it also show a pop up or heads-up notification.

sorry if this is so simple help if you know something

Notification.kt

`

```
package com.example.notifkos

import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat

const val notificationID = 1
const val channelID = "channel1"
const val titleExtra = "titleExtra"
const val messageExtra = "messageExtra"

class Notification : BroadcastReceiver()
{
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent)
    {
        val importance = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < N")
        }
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelID)

            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra(titleExtra))
            .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra(messageExtra))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .build()

        val  manager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        manager.notify(notificationID, notification)
    }
```

`Mainactivity.kt`

```
package com.example.notifkos

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.app.*
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.example.notifkos.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createNotificationChannel()
        }
        binding.submitButton.setOnClickListener { scheduleNotification() }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun scheduleNotification()
    {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, Notification::class.java)
        val title = binding.titleET.text.toString()
        val message = binding.messageET.text.toString()
        intent.putExtra(titleExtra, title)
        intent.putExtra(messageExtra, message)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            applicationContext,
            notificationID,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val time = getTime()
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            time,
            pendingIntent
        )
        showAlert(time, title, message)
    }

    private fun showAlert(time: Long, title: String, message: String)
    {
        val importance = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < N")
        }
        val date = Date(time)
        val dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getLongDateFormat(applicationContext)
        val timeFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(applicationContext)

        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Notification Scheduled")
            .setMessage(
                "Title: " + title +
                        "\nMessage: " + message +
                        "\nAt: " + dateFormat.format(date) + " " + timeFormat.format(date))
            .setPositiveButton("Okay"){_,_ ->}
            .show()
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun getTime(): Long
    {
        val minute = binding.timePicker.minute
        val hour = binding.timePicker.hour
        val day = binding.datePicker.dayOfMonth
        val month = binding.datePicker.month
        val year = binding.datePicker.year

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(year, month, day, hour, minute)
        return calendar.timeInMillis
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createNotificationChannel()
    {
        val name = "Notif Channel"
        val desc = "A Description of the Channel"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelID, name, importance)
        channel.description = desc
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

}
```

`
Well, how about adding more details. Like, what are you trying to accomplish, how are you doing it, what difficulties you have found with the approach, another approaches you have tried, etc. In summary, without code isn't a good question neither is with just code. Search for the balance!

there was nothing i could get my hands on

i have read android stuio docs so please dont tell me to read that please

Comment: Did you fix your issue ?
I encounter the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you did not create your notification channel according to your needs.

In function `createNotificationChannel()` you set importance of a channel to `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`

In source code it says:

> Default notification importance: shows everywhere, makes noise, **but
> does not visually intrude.**

You would get the wanted effect if you set importance to `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH`